# React, call function in another component

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ugtn3h?file=index.tsx)

Its a simple cart app where I am lising products with a button to add the product to a list.

The cart and the function to add to the cart is in a different component from where the products are.

How can I call the addToCart funtion from the App component where the button is clicked.

```
const handleClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>,
    item: IProduct
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Call the add to cart function
    Cart.addToCart(item);
  };
```

Comment: you can create a function than callback as property, dont hold your list at cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the addToCart function in the App component (father) and pass the function to the Cart component (child) as props, the cart state should also be handled at the App component.

Implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gf9r64?file=index.tsx

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can add that function in `parent` and pass it as `props` in a child so its can also access the `addToCart` function.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qdpl45?file=Cart.tsx